# how the data will distribute when using dist key for a column in redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am new to redshift. I dont understand which column will be suitable for setting a distribution key to get improved query performance. How to find the best column? and how the data will be distributed across the nodes using dist key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very wide question, its hard to provide your short answer. Anyways, let me try to summarize here, in `Redshift` there are two types of key, `distkey` and `sortkey`.
**distkey** - table’s distkey is the column on which it’s distributed to each node. Rows with the same value in this column are guaranteed to be on the same node.

**sortkey** - table’s sortkey is the column by which it’s sorted within each node. It should be applied for columns you usually do `order by`.

Lets focus on `distkey` here.

Distribution key could be of two types, 'Even' or 'All'. Distribution keys are used for achieve following.

- Distribute data evenly for parallel processing
- Minimize data movement

'All' distribution style should be used for - have slowly changing data, reasonable size (i.e., few millions but not 100s of millions of rows), missing common distribution key for frequent joins.
'Even' distribution style should be used for- tables not frequently joined or aggregated and large tables without acceptable candidate keys.

Here are some good materials to read.
https://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/deep-dive-on-amazon-redshift-64919704
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iuQgZDs-W7A
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-best-dist-key.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Distribution_examples.html

I hope this gives some way for you to move forward.

Comment: Thank you so much..links helps me a lot to understand.